# 2 questions on logarithms of $1\over x$ where $x = 10^k -1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, summation

Let $a_n$ denote the logarithm of the $n$'th sum of $\{{1\over9},{1\over99},{1\over999},...\}$, such that $a_n = \{\log({1\over9}+{1\over99}),\log({1\over9}+{1\over99}+{1\over999}),\log({1\over9}+{1\over99}+{1\over999}+{1\over9999}),\dots \}\implies$

$$
a_n = \log\!\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{10^k-1}\right),\;n > 0
$$

Then let $b_n$ denote the sum of $\{\pm\log(p),\pm\log(q),\pm\log(r),...\}$ such that $\{p,q,r,...\}$ are prime and $p<q<r<... \implies$

Which can be denoted as:
$$
b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \pm\log(p_k ),\;p_{k}>p_{k-1},\;\text{isPrime}(p_{k}) = \text{True}
$$

---

Consider the following:

$$
\begin{align}
n \mod 2 \equiv 1 &\implies& a_n &=\quad x\log(2) - y\log(3) + b_z\\
n \mod 2 \equiv 0 &\implies& a_n &=\quad x \log(3) b_z
\end{align}
$$

- $(1):$ Is this true for all $n>6$?
- $(2):$ Is it possible to calculate $z$, without knowing the sequence $p$?

Comment: What is $\pm\log(p)$? What is $b_z$?

Comment: @robjohn: $\pm \log(p) = +\log(p) \vee -\log(p)$, $b_z$ denotes the $z$th element in $b$.

Comment: for example, what is the value of $\pm\log(2)$ (if it doesn't have a single value, how do we perform the sum specified)? how does $z$ relate to any of the given information ($z$ never appears before)?

Comment: Did you mean $a_n=x\log(3)+b_z$ when $n\mod 2\equiv 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any rational number $u/v$ where the numerator and denominator have the prime factorizations
$$
u = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_U^{\alpha_U} \\
v = q_1^{\beta_1}q_2^{\beta_2}\cdots q_V^{\beta_V}
$$
then
$$
\log(u/v) = \sum \alpha_i \log p_i - \sum \beta_i \log q_i
$$
So your proposition seems to be that when you get the reduced fraction 
$$
\frac{u_n}{v_n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{10^k-1} = \exp(a_n)
$$
with $\gcd(u_n,v_n)=1$ then

1. The numerator $u_n$ is divisible by $2$ iff $n$ is not.
2. The denominator $v_n$ is always divisible by $3$ (this is not how it reads, but I guess for even $n$ you meant $-x\log 3+b_z$).
3. Except for powers of $2$ and $3$ the numerator and denominator are square-free, i.e.  $\alpha_i=1,\beta_i=1$ except if $p_i=2,q_i=3$.
4. Possibly you also meant that all primes other than $2$ that divide either $u_n$ or $v_n$ will also divide one of $u_j,v_j$ for all $j>n$.

Statement 1 is true. If you find the LCM of the denominators $D$ to write the sum
$$
\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{99}+\cdots+\frac{1}{10^{n+1}-1} = \frac{t_1}{D}+\frac{t_2}{D}+\cdots+\frac{t_{n+1}}{D}
$$
then $D$ and each $t_i$ are odd, so the numerator is even if $n$ is odd and vice-versa.

Statement 2 I suspect is also true but in theory could be violated. If $v_n=3^x c$ and $10^{n+2}-1 = 3^y d$ with $3\nmid cd$, then
$$
\frac{u_{n+1}}{v_{n+1}}=\frac{u_n}{3^xc}+\frac{1}{3^yd}
=\frac{3^yd u_n+3^xc}{3^{x+y}cd}
$$
If $x\ne y$ then $3^{\max(x,y)}\mid v_{n+1}$, but if $x=y$ and $3\mid d u_n+c$ then more powers of $3$ can be cancelled, and at this time I can't rule out the possibility of exactly cancelling so that $3$ does not divide $v_n,u_n$ for some $n$.

Statement 3 is false. $v_{21}$ is divisible by $121$ so will need a $-2\log 11$ in the series for $a_{21}$

Statement 4 is false. The numerators have unpredictable factorizations, so e.g. $2585837\mid u_7$, but it doesn't divide the $u_8,v_8,u_9$ or $v_9$ and I can't predict where it will appear next. The denominators have similar factorizations, because they must satisfy
$$
v_n \mid \operatorname{lcm}(9,99,\ldots,10^{n+1}-1) \\
\implies v_n \mid \operatorname{lcm}(9,99,\ldots,10^{n+1}-1,\ldots,10^j-1)~\mathrm{for~all}~j>n
$$
so for example since $37\mid 999$ it's not surprising that $37\mid v_i$ for $2\le i \le 49$. But it's possible that some primes get cancelled when taking the reduced fraction, for example $37\nmid v_{50}$, and $11\mid v_i$ for $1\le i \le 4$ but $11 \nmid v_5$.